# Administrative GUI: Should I use Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, wijmo

I need to make a administrative GUI with lots of functionality like lists, forms, navigation, etc.

I have looked at twitter Bootstrap and this looks really good, but it is missing some features that I must incorporate. I could integrate Jquery for Bootstrap and this helps but all the (minified) resource files together in my solution are over 250KB.

I looked at some commercial products like Wijmo which I am also considering, but I am woried that I get stuck somewhere down the line.
ExtJS is also a suggested option that I am looking at.

Can anyone give some alternative CSS3 + Javascript (jquery) + HTML5 framework for administrative GUIs?
Only new browsers need to be supported, not ie6 - ie8.

Comment: SO is not a recommendation site.

Comment: @Daedalus that's not helpful at all

Comment: @GantengX I would check the dates before commenting on something.  This was well over a year ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is nice for making a website, for an administrative GUI i would look at a Javascript application framework such as [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/).